# Rotational bending in Timoshenko beam theory

Tags: structural-engineering, beam

The [Wikipedia article on Timoshenko beam theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timoshenko_beam_theory) says:

> The model takes into account shear deformation and rotational bending effects,

I am familiar with shear deformation, but what is meant by "rotational bending"? Google search yields no good explanations of the term, so what do we mean by that? **What kind of rotational bending does the Timoshenko model account for that the Euler beam model does not?**

Comment: Why not check the Timoshenko original text instead of wikipedia?

Comment: If used to say "rotational inertia effects" before some know-all (or know-nothing) edited it.

Comment: @alephzero "If" - you do mean "it", as in the Wikipedia article?

Comment: @S.Rotos Yes. But you can't correct typos in comment after 5 minutes. There have been so many edits to that page I got bored trying to track down exactly when it happened (and possibly revert it, depending on what else was in the edit).

Comment: {This is from memory; please bear with.} If I recall correctly, the Tim. beam theory does *not* assume that plane sections (specifically those normal to the beam axis) remain planar. This is in distinct contrast to Euler-Bernouli beam theory, which does assume that. HTH

Comment: @alephzero Alright, thank you! So basically the article was talking about inertial effects, which are relevant only in the dynamic case.